# CakePHP - Fix malformed URL parameters

Tags: cakephp

When i'm editing an register of my database the url is `/edit/168` (for example). But if i change this url to `/edit/168'` or `/edit/168=` give me an error of database.

How can i validate the id before searching in the database?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `preg_replace` to remove any non-numeric characters.

So in your action you would have something like:

```
public function edit($id){ 
// remove the invalid characters
$item = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $id);
}
```

You then use the formatted `$item` in your sql query in place of `$id`

Comment: No problem. Happy hacking :)